# Which kind of user's information I can use for create unique user's key?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've next problem:
I need create unique user key based on user's information what I can receive from user's request to my web-page (ASP.NET).

I'll use this key for auto-login functionality (I know about cookie ^^)

What kind of information I can use?
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are creating the key yourself then use one of .NET's integral types (`int` or `long` tend to be the most commonly used) or a `Guid`.

If you are using user-supplied data then use something like an email address that is unique to the user.

Comment: If you use something like an email address, make sure you do not disclose this key to others (like /user_profile.asp?id=aaa@gmail.com )

Comment: No, you don't understand my problem. I need unique key, which I can dynamically generate when user open my page. Like "remember me"

Comment: @misho, Andrew says you can dynamically generate a GUID at run time. If you store this in a cookie then you can use this in a "remember me" function

Answer (score 0):

A good idea would be to concatenate some text part from the user's information (eg: name) with an autoincremented number. This way the key would be alphanumeric and at the same time unique.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, imho. What is the environment of your site (intranet/Internet, open/closed registration etc.)?

Do you need to just "recognize" a user who comes back to your site after some time?
In this case, cookie with a GUID is probably just fine.

Or do you want to "recognize" users (from a previously known list) without them typing anything at all?
Then, a proper solution is to use either integrated authentication (provided that the users are in the domain, that is, your site must be intranet-only) or HTTPS with client authentication using SSL certificates (works for Internet as well).